# Enabling and Adding Migrations after deleting Migrations folder

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I took `the Project failed to build` error when I tried to update my database.

I found that trying to add migrations after deleting Migrations folder and Migration History table in database solves this problem.

Although I did this, neither "`Enable-Migrations`", "`Add-Migration`" commands nor "`Update-Database`" command works.

I need enabling and adding migrations. What can be the reason of this problem and what is the solution?

Comment: What happens in the console when you do that?. If you don't give more iformation we cannot guess if that's becasue it's raining, because it's too cold or because of a planet conjunction.

Comment: @JotaBe Unfortunately, I only have an The Project failed to build error.

Comment: Mmmm, ok. Then try to build the project before running the console commands. It looks like the problem is previous to the console commands. Let me know if the project builds succcesfully. As you said you can remove ht Migrations folder and run the `Enable-Migrations` later without problems.